# Python,Ctypes - WindowsError: access violation

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'm developing instrument drivers for testing at work.  It's first developed in 
C using the IVI/Visa standard. I am then using a python wrapper for a dll of the C to use the functions in the python environment. However with the current one I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/CAS/Development/LvDrivers/Python/Python_wrapper/ADIag81110a.py", line 1362, in <module>
      PGEN.ConfigureTransitionCoupling(1, "1")
  File "D:/CAS/Development/LvDrivers/Python/Python_wrapper/ADIag81110a.py", line 1305, in ConfigureTransitionCoupling
      ADIag81110aLib().ADIag81110a_ConfigureTransitionCoupling(  self.vi,  transitionEnabling ,  channelName    )
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000031
```

It happens with any function I use from the C.  All of the functions work correctly when they are ran directly in C. He is is the C definition of that function:

```
ViStatus _VI_FUNC ADIag81110a_ConfigureTransitionCoupling (ViSession vi,
                                              ViInt32 transitionEnabling,   ViChar channelName[])
{
   ViStatus error = VI_SUCCESS;
   checkErr( Ivi_LockSession (vi, VI_NULL));

   viCheckParm(Ivi_SetAttributeViInt32 (vi, channelName, ADIAG81110A_ATTR_TRANSITION_COUPLING, 
                                     0, transitionEnabling), 2, "Transition Coupling");  

Error:
   Ivi_UnlockSession (vi, VI_NULL);
   return error;
}
```

The python might seem a little complicated but i'll only be posting the code that I feel is relevant to declaration of the ConfigureTransitionCoupling function that I'm using as an example and the ctypes declarations:

```
import os
import visa_exceptions
from visa_messages import completion_and_error_messages
from vpp43_constants import *
from vpp43_types import *
from ctypes import cdll
if os.name == 'nt':
   from ctypes import windll
else:
   from ctypes import CFUNCTYPE as FUNCTYPE
import warnings

class Singleton(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
      it = cls.__dict__.get("__it__")
      if it is not None:
        return it
    cls.__it__ = it = object.__new__(cls)
    it.init(*args, **kwds)
    return it


class ADIag81110a_lib(Singleton):
    def __call__(self, force_cdecl=False):
    if self.__lib is None or self.__cdecl_lib is None:
        self.load_library()
    if force_cdecl:
        return self.__cdecl_lib
    return self.__lib
def init(self):
    self.__lib = self.__cdecl_lib = None

def load_library(self, path=None):
    if os.name == 'nt':
        path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\IVI\Bin\ADIag81110a_32.dll"
        self.__lib = windll.LoadLibrary(path)
        self.__cdecl_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(path)
    elif os.name == 'posix':
        if not path:
            path = "please put path to unix/linix here"
        self.__lib = self.__cdecl_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(path)
    else:
        self.__lib = self.__cdecl_lib = None
        raise visa_exceptions.OSNotSupported, os.name
    self.__initialize_library_functions()
    return None

def __initialize_library_functions(self):
   self.__set_argument_types("ADIag81110a_ConfigureTransitionCoupling", [   ViSession ,  ViInt32 ,  ViChar ])

def __set_argument_types(self, inst_function, types, force_cdecl=False,   may_be_missing=True):
    if force_cdecl:
        library = self.__cdecl_lib
    else:
        library = self.__lib
    try:
        getattr(library, inst_function).argtypes = types
    except AttributeError:
        if not may_be_missing:
            raise

 ADIag81110aLib = ADIag81110a_lib()

 class ADIag81110a():

      def ConfigureTransitionCoupling(self ,  transitionEnabling ,  channelName    ):
            ADIag81110aLib().ADIag81110a_ConfigureTransitionCoupling(  self.vi,  transitionEnabling ,  channelName    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
   #This initilises the communication with the instrument
   PGEN = ADIag81110a("GPIB0::10::INSTR")

   test = PGEN.ReadOutputImpedance("1")

   print test
```

I have looked at other people posting about their error and I feel they are using C-types in a different way to me so I am unable to apply their solutions.

Any help is appreciated.  This is also my first post on stack overflow so feel free to point out any issues with my post :)

Comment: Probably should make it a little clearer.  It may be obvious but for the sake of the philosophy of the site.  My question is how do I solve the Windows access violation error bearing in mind that this structure has worked for a good number instruments I have already done without any error like this.

Comment: Is it possible to add some printfs (or some other type of logging) to your C code to narrow down to a single line where this error occurs? I don't see a problem with your code, but of course there's a good bit of it not shown. You might also do a search in your project and see if 0x31, or 49, is hard-coded anywhere.

Comment: This gives some hints on how to debug your Python C extensions: https://docs.python.org/3.5/faq/extending.html#how-do-i-debug-an-extension

Comment: If I was to add a printf in the C file where would it print when it's called from python? would it print in the python console?

Comment: I'm not sure, honestly. Just trying to think of a few things your could try to help track it down. I'd say just try it and see. Ideally you can use gdb, as shown in the link I gave you. You'll be able to track down the problem much more quickly with that.

Comment: Okay I'll read into the gdb and see if I can use it.  If not i'll try the printing.

Comment: In case you are wondering Chad I tried the printf method and prints in the c file inside the dll do just appear in the python console window.

Comment: Awesome! Hopefully you can use some old-school printf debugging to track down your issue.

Comment: Show the C typedefs for `ViSession` and `ViChar`, and how you're defining them in ctypes.

Comment: They are defined in a file called vpp43_types.py.  ViSession is defined like this: `ViSession, ViPSession, ViASession = _type_triplet(ViObject)`    ViChar is defined like so: `ViChar, ViPChar, ViAChar          = _type_triplet(_ctypes.c_char)`

Comment: The function wants a `ViChar *` (a C string is a `char` array, which is passed to a function as a `char` pointer), so change the type in `argtypes` to `POINTER(ViChar)`.

Comment: Where are you saying to do that sorry? I tried doing it in the line where the arguments are set for the function: `self.__set_argument_types("ADIag81110a_ConfigureTransitionCoupling", [   ViSession ,  ViInt32 ,  ViChar ])` but it gives an error saying POINTER is not defined.

Comment: Okay I released I had to import all of ctypes to get that to work and it appears to have fixed the issue.  I need to test it on other functions to be sure